# PUT Request parse error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a website where a user stores resources and makes articles about them. At this time, i'm building the comments section where users can make comments in the articles. I have a put request which is triggered from controller which sends the id of the article and the comment.

but i receive the following error,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 1
    at parse (/home/themis/webappionio/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /home/themis/webappionio/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/themis/webappionio/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
    at done (/home/themis/webappionio/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/themis/webappionio/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

here is my server.js:

```
//defining Articles Model

var ArticleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _creatorname: String,
     title : String,
     body : String,
     resource: String,
     published : String,
     comments: [{
         _commentorname: String,
          content : String,
          date : String
     }]
 });

var Articles = mongoose.model("Articles", ArticleSchema);

//pushing comment into the specific article

app.put("/home/:id", function(req,res){
    var _commentorname = req.user.username;
    var content = req.body.comment;
    var date = moment().tz("Europe/Athens").format("DD/MM/YY HH:mm");
    Articles.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id, 
        {$push: {"comments" : {_commentorname: _commentorname, content: content, date: date}}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true}, 
        function(err, article) {
                console.log(err);
       }
    );
});
```

My controller :

```
$scope.addComment = function(id, comment) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log(comment);
        $http.put("/home/" + id, comment)
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.all();
        });
    };
```

and my html form:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
                        <input type="text" id="userComment" ng-model="comment" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">     
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addComment(article._id, comment)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Add Comment</button>
                        </span>

                    </div>
```

Here is my final server.js

```
app.put("/home/:id", function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    Articles.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id, 
        {$push: {"comments" : {_commentorname: req.user.username, content:req.body.comment}}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true}, 
        function (err, results) {
            if (err) 
            {
                res.send("there was a problem updating the information: " + err);
            }
            else {
                res.format({
                    json: function() {
                        res.json(results);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: It would help if you learned to interpret stack traces a little better. The error source is coming from the "body parser", which means the formatted JSON being sent has a structural error. It also helps to understand that just because you "project" uses various technolgy components in the stack, it doesn't mean your "problem" or "question" here involves "all" of them. It's generally expected you narrow these things down first and ask and tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `comment` here is not actually being sent as an `Object` but just as a "string". So you need to structure the `Object` instead.

So correct the angular controller code:

```
$scope.addComment = function(id, comment) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log(comment);
        $http.put("/home/" + id, { "comment": comment})
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.all();
        });
    };
```

Comment: @ExWei You also took an incorrect guess and were told you got it wrong

Comment: well it worked: i pushed the object as Blake said above. i pushed all i wanted except the date format which if i try to push date also, nothing pushed at all

Comment: @Nickbo Well there is in fact no reason why that would be a problem. Your schema type is presently a "String" for the `"date"` property, so it should just stringify. I personally think you should be storing as `Date` instead, and also not trying to force a string into a local timezone. But that is not what the question or error encountered were about. Remember to [Accept your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) as well. Since I notice you as yet have not accepted any.

Answer (score -1):

**New Answer:**

Actually it looks like that you are submitting in the Angular controller the comment variable in a "raw" way instead of sending it as JSON, you need to change it to the

```
$scope.addComment = function(id, comment) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log(comment);
        $http.put("/home/" + id, {comment: comment})
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.all();
        });
    };
```

**Old Answer:**

I think it throws the error because you format the date to the unusual format "DD/MM/YY HH:mm", if you would use native JS object it would work, e.g.

```
var date = moment().tz("Europe/Athens").toDate()
```